# In Xceed WPF PropertyGrid how to make Search and Sort buttons invisible

Tags: wpf, propertygrid, xceed

I would like to make the Alphabetic Sort and Search bar invisible on the Xceed WPF PropertyGrid. How would that be done?  I have read through the list of object attributes for the PropertyGrid and did not see any property relating to the search button as a separate UI element within the PG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set following properties:

```
 <extToolkit:PropertyGrid ShowSearchBox="False" ShowSortOptions="False" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Acutally, found it:

```
        PG.ShowSearchBox = false;
        PG.ShowSortOptions = false;
```